# Static Application Security Testing (SAST) Tool for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security, continuous-integration, static-analysis, sast

I'm looking for software that I can integrate into a CI pipeline of a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) project. The tool should check the code for security issues.

For Python code, I'm happy with [`bandit`](https://pypi.org/project/bandit/). For JavaScript, I have seen [ESLint](https://eslint.org/), but I think it is only about formatting. Similar to Flake8 in Python.

I'm primarily looking for [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) tools, but if somebody can strongly recommend a non-gratis tools from personal experience that would be interesting as well.

### What I've tried

- [`eslint-plugin-security`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-security), but that is not maintained.
- [`semgrep`](https://github.com/returntocorp/semgrep), but I'm uncertain if there are good security testing rules for JavaScript
- [`nodejsscan`](https://github.com/ajinabraham/nodejsscan): Based on semgrep; looks good but takes way too long to run

Answer (score 3):

I think [sonarqube](https://www.sonarqube.org/features/multi-languages/javascript/) could be a nice fit. It's meant to integrate with CI and spots certain security problems in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of aspects to static analysis in JS:

- Linting (e.g. eslint & plugins);
- Code coverage (e.g. jest);
- Supply Chain Analysis (e.g. yarn audit)
- Code smells, anti-patterns etc (e.g. SonarQube)

Here is an [article on the topic](https://nikgrozev.com/2020/03/22/improve-your-typescript-with-static-analysis/) which I found useful. It's about TypeScript, but most of it should apply to plain JavaScript. It goes in depth about how to set up the tools.